# Automatically unlock LUKS partition using a key on an USB drive on Debian Jessie

Tags: boot, usb, debian, systemd, luks

I am trying to have the encrypted root partition be unlocked on boot automatically using a connected USB drive on a fresh installation of Debian Jessie (no non-systemd upgrade). After following a couple of tutorials on the web, I am stuck, as it still asks for the passphrase right after boot. This is what I've done so far:

Created the key on the USB drive:

```
root@fls:~# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdc bs=512 seek=1 count=60
```

Copied the appropriate part as the key into a temp file:

```
root@fls:~# dd if=/dev/sdc bs=512 skip=1 count=4 > tempKeyFile.bin
```

Added that key to the encrypted partition config:

```
root@fls:~# cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/md1 --key-file=- tempKeyFile.bin
```

Found out the ID of the USB drive:

```
root@fls:~# ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/ | grep sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 usb-0_USB_DRIVE_00000000000165A3-0:0 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 usb-0_USB_DRIVE_00000000000165A3-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdc1
```

Changed `/etc/crypttab` like that:

```
#md1_crypt UUID=e53fc075-0afa-4018-b187-912f8f355699 none luks
md1_crypt UUID=ED04-17F5 /dev/disk/by-id/usb-0_USB_DRIVE_00000000000165A3-0:0 luks,tries=3,keyfile-size=2048,keyfile-offset=512
```

Updated the systemd generator files:

```
systemctl --system daemon-reload
```

I am not sure whether that `UUID=` entry is correct, as it is actually the UUID of `/dev/sdc1` and [apparently there will not be](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64457/uuid-of-a-drive-that-wont-show-up-in-dev-disk-by-uuid-or-blkid) a UUID for `/dev/sdc`, so what do I have to enter there?

Also, did I miss anything else that would prevent the key on the USB drive to unlock the partition? When I do `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/md1` it does show two Key Slots, so the key is properly configured, I guess.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are almost correct. I used your instructions to setup automatic unlock of LUKS partitions here, but not /. ;-)

What seems wrong to me, is the **UUID** you use. You seems to confuse the UUID with the setup of the keyfile on USB. the UUID points to the uuid of the LUKS partition you want to unlock. So you don't want to change it from the line above, unless I have misunderstood.

I would use in `/etc/crypttab` instead:

```
md1_crypt UUID=e53fc075-0afa-4018-b187-912f8f355699 /dev/disk/by-id/usb-0_USB_DRIVE_00000000000165A3-0:0 luks,tries=3,keyfile-size=2048,keyfile-offset=512
```

One important step is to add the **needed modules** to the *initramfs/initcpio* so that the kernel can read the USB key.

On *Ubuntu*, I have changed `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` with *rtsx_usb{_ms,_sdmmc,}* and *memstick* because I use the *SD card reader* instead. But for the USB key, you will need *usb_storage*, *usbhid* (?), *hid_generic* (?), *hid* (?), *memstick* and may be others.

then run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and reboot. It should work

Answer (score -1):

re-create the key  AFTER mounting the usb to somewhere    that  essentially  did a  cat > /dev/null

```
   # sudo mount /dev/sdc /cryptusb
   # dd if=/dev/urandom of=/cryptusb/keyfile bs=512 seek=1 count=60
   #  dd if=/cryptusb/keyfile bs=512 skip=1 count=4 > tempKeyFile.bin
```

OR

```
   # cat  /cryptusb/keyfile > /tmp/keyfile.bin
```

THEN use the **'PARTUUID'** from blkid  to inject into  **"/etc/crypttab'**